# Null Reference Exception was Unhandled

Tags: vb.net, exception, reference, null

This is a very simple code. I am just beginning to use vb. Im making a game where you try to solve a puzzle in the least amount of time and least amount of clicks. Every time I debug the program, it highlights the Clicks and FinalTime and says Null Reference Exception was Unhandled. I declared Clicks and FinalTime globally

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Clicks As Integer = 0  'The variable that counts the number of times you clicked
Dim Time As Integer 'The vairable that holds the time
Dim TimeMin As Integer 'The variable that holds the minutes
Dim TimeSec As Integer  'The variable that holds the seconds
Dim FinalTime As String 'The variable that holds the final time (minutes and seconds)
Dim NumArray() As Integer
Dim NumArray1() As String

Private Sub Times

    Time = Time + 1
    TimeSec = TimeSec + 1 
    TimeMin = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSec \ 60) 
    If Time >= 60 Then
        Time = 0
    End If
    FinalTime = TimeMin & " min " & Time & " seconds" 
    lblTime.Text = FinalTime 
End Sub
Private Sub Record(ByVal NumArray() As Integer, ByVal NumArray1() As String)

    For i As Integer = 0 To 1000 
        NumArray(i) = Clicks 'Problem is here
        i = +1
        Array.Sort(NumArray) 
    Next i
    lblRecordClicks.Text = NumArray(0) & " Clicks" 
    For k As Integer = 0 To 1000 
        NumArray1(k) = FinalTime 'Problem is here
        k = +1
        Array.Sort(NumArray1) 
    Next k
    lblRecordTime.Text = NumArray1(0) 
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you declare `Clicks` and `FinalTime`? If you don't declare them then they will be null..  Maybe try using [Option Explicit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329)

Comment: I would also recommend turning on Option Strict. You can turn them on by putting it at the very top of the class file or do it globally in the project settings.

Comment: Please add the code where you declare the arrays passed to this function and the code that calls this function

Comment: Where do you declare the two arrays passed to the Record function? How do you pass them?

Comment: Looks like NumArray and NumArray1 is not instantiated but only declared so when you are going through the loop, it bombs out at NumArray(i).

Comment: How would I fix this though? And what does instantiated mean? Im sorry, im new at using Vb and don't really understand the "computer" talk yet.

Answer (score 2):

Rule #1. Strings in VB.NET are not the same as Strings in VB6.

In VB6 you can say

```
Dim text as String
```

and you would have `text = ""` initialized

In VB.NET you need

```
Dim text as String = vbNullString
```

or

```
Dim text as New String
```

The same applies to arrays of string (or any other array)

```
Dim arr as String() ' This makes arr = Nothing
arr = New String(10) { } ' This allocates an array with 11 items (0..10)
```

or

```
Dim arr as String() = New String(10) {}
```

or

```
Dim arr() As String = New String(10) {}
```

or

```
Dim arr() = New String(10) {}
```

or

```
Dim arr = New String(10) {}
```

See related: [Classes and arrays how to initialize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965357/classes-and-arrays-how-to-initialize)